# How to jUnit Assert a Grails Controller Update of a Database column?

Tags: java, grails, junit, assert, sql-update

I have a grails controller which takes a simple string and updates a column in the DB by id. I want to write a jUnit test for this operation to make sure the update went through correctly....

```
  @Test
 void "testUpdateNameOnMonsterById"() {

    controller.params.id = 8;
    controller.params.name = 'Godzilla';

    controller.updateMosterNameById();
    // what are the different jUnit assertetions that need to happen at this point?
```

For example should I query the DB and do assertEquals or assertTrue?

Any sample code with jUnit asserts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using spock?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following with spock:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(MonsterController)
class MonsterControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test updateMonsterNameById"() {
        given:
            def monsterId = 8
            def monsterName = 'Godzilla'
            params.id = monsterId
            params.name = monsterName
        when:
            controller.updateMonsterNameById()
        then:
            monsterName == Monster.get( monsterId ).name
    }
}
```